# VBA Vlookup Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a Vlookup macro where the the lookup value is located in cell C18 in a closed workbook.  I tried to creating this code shown below, but all I receive is a message stating:

Compile error:

```
Expected end of statement
```

Can you please assist?

```
Sub Vlookup()

Dim myRng
Set myRng = Range("Ledger_Account_2")
Range("F15") = "=VLookup('C:\Users\fbdXXXX\Documents\[PRE500KPC90 - BBB Monthly Reclass - 042023.xlsm]Journal Entry'!C18,Range("MyRng,")2,0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where you have: `...("MyRng,")...` try: `.(" & MyRng.Address & ")...`

Comment: You have an errant comma; `Range("MyRng,")2` should probably be `Range("MyRng"), 2`

Answer (score 2):

### Writing a `VLOOKUP` Formula

- Note that this will only work if the source file is closed.

```vb
Sub Vlookup()

    Const SRC_FOLDER As String = "C:\Users\fbdXXXX\Documents\"
    Const SRC_FILE As String = "PRE500KPC90 - BBB Monthly Reclass - 042023.xlsm"
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Journal Entry"
    Const SRC_CELL As String = "C18"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
            
    Dim myRng As Range: Set myRng = ws.Range("Ledger_Account_2")
    
    Dim Formula As String: Formula = "=VLOOKUP('" _
        & SRC_FOLDER & "[" & SRC_FILE & "]" & SRC_SHEET _
        & "'!" & SRC_CELL & "," & myRng.Address & ",2,0)"
    
    'Debug.Print Formula
    
    ws.Range("F15").Formula = Formula

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response.  The  Dim myRng As Range: Set myRng = ws.Range("Ledger_Account_2") is returning a Method'Range' of object'_Worksheet failed error.  The source sheet is closed, but this error pops up and I have declared "Ledger_Account_2" as a range name.  Can you please help with this error?